# Android buttons' text moves left when clicked

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I have this layout. When a button is clicked, another activity is started.

If you press the back button then, you will see the text in the buttons is left aligned. Can it be solved?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/negro"
tools:context="com.sakrodiseno.taxiclic.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/blanco"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:text="@string/solicitarServicio"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@color/azulCielo" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="3dp" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/direccion"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/blanco" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerDirecciones"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/pasajero"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/blanco" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerPasajeros"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/fecha"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/blanco" />

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtFecha"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="date"
                android:onClick="seleccionarFecha()"
                android:textColor="@color/blanco" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtHora"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="time"
                android:textColor="@color/blanco" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/nota"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/blanco" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtNota"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLength="100"
        android:textColor="@color/blanco" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSolicitarServicio"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:onClick="solicitar"
    android:text="@string/solicitarServicio"
    android:textColor="@color/blanco" />

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/TableRow01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDirecciones"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="administrarDirecciones"
            android:text="Direcciones"
            android:textColor="@color/blanco" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnPasajeros"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="administrarPasajeros"
            android:text="Pasajeros"
            android:textColor="@color/blanco" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm having the same problem in every activity in my app. This is an example of onClick methods:

```
public void administrarDirecciones(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Direcciones.class);
    intent.putExtra("CODUSU", codusu);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: view looks okay, can you share any of your onclick methods.

Comment: Done. I added an onClick method.

Comment: add the long click listner to see how it looks, or add text/lable gravity in xml file at the button

Comment: Try to add this : android:layout_width="0dp" properties to your button in xml.